# Algolia Laravel Scout complex where clauses and eager loading

Tags: laravel, algolia, laravel-scout

Since Laravel Scout doesn't support more complex **where** clauses than simple numeric comparisons.

I checked the source code and I found the following lines

```
if (!empty($models = $model->getScoutModelsByIds($builder, $modelKeys))) {
                    $instances = $instances->merge($models->load($searchable->getRelations($modelClass)));
                }
```

The **instances** is what is returned from Algolia search, so for example the following search essentially returns the $instances variable.

```
Mode::search('something')->get();
```

the **$model** is the searchable model and the **getScoutModelsByIds** what It basically does is a query to the database like

```
public function getScoutModelsByIds(){
       $model->whereIn('id', $modelKeys)->get();
}
```

I was wondering if I apply any kind of **where** clauses or **addSelect**, or **with** eager loading,  on the model before actually retrieving the data from the database, is it a good idea ?

For example

```
$model->where('some condition')->whereIn('id', $modelKeys)->get();
```

and instead of using lazy loading

```
$instances = $instances->merge($models->load($searchable->getRelations($modelClass)));
```

use the **with** function before retrieving the data from db.

For example

```
$model->where('some condition')->whereIn('id', $modelKeys)->with('relationships')->get();
```